# Как сделать отображение чата на Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Есть база данных в которой хранятся все сообщения, сервер их подгружает, но возникла проблема в визуализации этих же сообщений. То есть нужен виджет, в котором можно выделить конкретное сообщение для последующего редактирования/удаления сообщения. Сейчас сделал на QTextEdit, но нет возможности выбрать конкретное сообщение.

Comment: зависит же только от вашей фантазии, я бы делал на QListView, можно и на таблицах, можно и свой виджет написать

Answer (score -1):

Рекомендую QTableWidget или  QTableView. Последнее проще. А там уже и полный список и регулировка высоты и перенос и всё, всё,всё,  как у Винни Пуха